# C# Bitmap Draw Image is Scaling

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

My setup takes .png images (with transparency) and stacks these images as layers on top of each other to form one image. The first batch I did worked perfectly. This second batch for some reason is scaling all of the images.

1. All of the images are 2000px x 2000px (I have individually checked each one and I can also see that Windows Explorer recognizes all of their dimensions.
2. All images are *.png files with transparent backgrounds.

In the `Merge()` function: I checked to see what the output `width` and `height` (and same of the image object) were and every single time they all came out to be 2000 (which is what it should be).

Below is a screen shot of the actual output vs what it should be. Again, I did this with different images (all 2000px x 2000px) and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure what is going on here.

[image]

```
    public static Bitmap TestIt()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
            Path.Combine(dir, "body1.png"),
            Path.Combine(dir, "head5.png"),
            Path.Combine(dir, "legs2.png"),
            Path.Combine(dir, "background2.png")
        };

        //Get List of Bitmaps from URLs
        List<Bitmap> bitmaps = ConvertUrlsToBitmaps(list);

        if (bitmaps.Any())
        {
            return Merge(bitmaps);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
       
    }


    private static Bitmap Merge(List<Bitmap> images)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        
        try
        {
            // Get max width and height of the image
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                width = image.Width > width ? image.Width : width;
                height = image.Height > height ? image.Height : height;
            }

            // merge images
            bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                foreach (var image in images)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return bitmap;

    }


    private static List<Bitmap> ConvertUrlsToBitmaps(List<string> imageUrls)
    {
        List<Bitmap> bitmapList = new List<Bitmap>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string imgUrl in imageUrls)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imgUrl);
                bitmapList.Add(bmp);
            }            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return bitmapList;
    }
```

Comment: Inspect the images with a tool that will tell you the DPI of the images. My bet is that these are different from the first set. Right-click on an image in File Explorer, then click “Properties”. In the image properties window, switch to the “Details” tab. In the details tab, scroll down to the “Image” sub-section, and look for the “Horizontal resolution” and “Vertical resolution” stats which should have a value in “dpi”

Comment: @EmondErno I really thought you hit the nail on the head - but all of the images are 96dpi - just the same as the last set

Answer (score 0):

Alright...I solved it.

I added a Rectangle object that will identify both position and size.
Then I forced the `drawImage` function to draw according to position and size

Here's the update

```
private static Bitmap Merge(List<Bitmap> images)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        
        try
        {
            // Get max width and height of the image
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                width = image.Width > width ? image.Width : width;
                height = image.Height > height ? image.Height : height;
            }

            // merge images
            bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

            //*** Added a Rectangle object that will identify starting position and size
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(width, height));

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                foreach (var image in images)
                {
                    //*** Force the system to draw the image at location AND size
                    g.DrawImage(image, rect);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return bitmap;

    }
```

Comment: The foreach to get the max size can be simpler: var width = images.Max(i => i.Width); var height = images.Max(i => i.Height); This is not faster but I find it more readable and elegant.

Comment: It looks like you are scaling the images to the biggest image. That might introduce some artifacts depending on the interpolation settings.